# How to remember last tab used with PHP form submit?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form inside one of many tabs, but when it submits it goes back to the first one.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-control">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab" aria-expanded="true">Tab1</a></li>
                <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2" aria-expanded="false">Tab2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h3 class="panel-title">Text</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab" class="tab-pane fade active in">
                <form class="form-group" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input class="form-control description" name="description[]" placeholder="Description here">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="update" type="submit" value="Save">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane fade">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP fetches form and update database and redirects:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    //database update

    //current url + tab
    header("Location: {$url->getCurentUrl()}#tab3");
}
```

The link is correct, but the tab won't update using the #tab in url, anyone have alternative methods to set active tab to last tab used?

Comment: Please, post code for the tabs.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't have an element with the ID "tab3". If there is something below "tab-2" you are missing the "-".

Comment: Just a general tip, but if you don't have to submit the form the classic way, just use AJAX to send it and you don't have to restore the state of the site or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code ...might be helpful to you as it's for me so...

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
  localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
});
var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
if(activeTab){
  $('#action-tab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
}
```